# Twitter bootstrap changeable vertical/horizontal form layout with little modification

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making an app where there are lots of forms and i am fatigued at the thought of referring to the form reference for the tricky vertical aligned forms and horizontal aligned forms.

I want a final snippet that will be my point of reference when i want a vertical and a horizontal form.

For a vertical form(forms aligned vertically) i use this code

https://jsfiddle.net/bgebzwqd/11/

```
<form role="form">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">First name</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="address">Second name</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pwd">Password</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
       </div>
    </form>
```

For horizontal forms i have this

https://jsfiddle.net/0jwzxoe2/20/

```
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <label class="control-label">One</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <label class="control-label ">Two</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <label class="control-label ">Three</label>
                 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3">
              <label class="control-label ">Four</label>
                 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3">
              <label class="control-label ">Five</label>
                 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

In the first form(vertical forms), how can i control the width of the form bootstrap way(trying and avoiding custom css)

In the second, i want to have the button at the bottom and also have some spacing vertically. In the current example, there seem to be no space.

To solve the problem, i want to avoid using custom css and try solving this using what's available in bootstrap only.

Comment: Do you want single form to be work in both the screen? is it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">First name</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="address">Second name</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <div class="form-group col-md-4">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: could you offer a little explanation what you have done.

Comment: Bootstrap divides each row in 12 grids. If size of your screen is extra small (xs) or small (sm), each of your field will occupy all 12 columns.. but if screen size is medium, it will occupy 3 cols.. you can also change col sizes.. but total col in the row must be 12

Comment: May be I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this for vertical forms

https://jsfiddle.net/codebreaker87/zqjva21d/

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <style>.width500{width:500px;margin-left:30px;}</style>
                                      <form role="form">
                                        <div class="row">
       <div class="form-group  width500">
          <label for="name">First name</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group  width500 ">
          <label for="address">Second name</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group  width500">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group  width500">
          <label for="pwd">Password</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group  width500">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
       </div>
     </div>
    </form>

    </div>
```

For horizontal forms https://jsfiddle.net/codebreaker87/zqjva21d/21/

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<style>.mb{margin-bottom:20px;}.ml{margin-left:15px;}</style>
            <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label">One</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label ">Two</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label ">Three</label>
                 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label ">Four</label>
                 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label ">Five</label>
                 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>

              <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label ">Six</label>
                 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12 ml ">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
    </div>
```